# Animate Curve along mesh surface

Tags: animation, mesh, bezier-curves

i am trying to find a way to aproach, animating a curve along a mesh surface, like having a wire creating a mesh.
I thought about having a curve snapped along the mesh and then animate the wires.
 Do you have any reference tutorial or any idea how to aproach it? Here is a reference image:[image]

and here is a second:
[image]

Thank alot

Comment: I guess what you want is not clear and need a little bit more explanation

Comment: Yeah i know, i dont have even have a reference video, i was asked from aclient that has a ed model of a head. if there is a way somehow to be created from wires.

Comment: you mean a wire moves until it creates the shape of a head? With Empty Hook you can control the vertices of a curve

Comment: i mean having a wire going along the periphepy (maybe spiral move) of an object, untill it completes the shape. Here is an image that resembles it https://www.google.gr/search?rlz=1C1MSIM_enGR760GR760&biw=1920&bih=943&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=WhqIW5qAAcedsAfZ05vIAQ&q=spiral+head+esher&oq=spiral+head+esher&gs_l=img.3...9006.11434.0.11948.9.9.0.0.0.0.128.1099.0j9.9.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.1.122...0j0i30k1j0i10i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.wIvBJ6IXPSo#imgrc=aw971AknW-lDFM:

Comment: oh ok interesting

Comment: perhaps create a mesh for the head, then a bandage that will stick to the head with a shrinkwrap, then put some hooks or bones to control the bandage, and use the Projection Painting technique to paint the bandage? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQy5jn9dWrs     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxD0qaTFZnk    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZDMFkj8GqA

Comment: it is not the exact image, i am still trying to find a better reference

Comment: I changed the reference we a much more acurate,This image was created with c4d

Comment: is it supposed to move and if so, how?

Comment: I think trying to fill the shape, having like an infinte cable tha goes all along the surface until it fill the shape.

Comment: Do you need to move the noodles or are they just lengthening along still curves? You can create some cylinders, then with Array + Curve modifiers, you increase the Count of the Array and the noodles will lengthen along the curves. If you put some Hooks along the curves you can also move the noodles if needed. Maybe those hooks could stick to invisible spherical shapes...

Comment: i thought about faking it, i dont think that i will do it for the client, it does not have good value for money, but i thought about creating a script. In pseudocode, it is like trying to connect all dots without overlapping.

Comment: So why not create spiral curves, then you duplicate a cylinders along them with an array modifier

Comment: Because it will not have the detail, of working with a head model or other more complex shapes.

Comment: You could create your shape, then create and extrude a curve along this shape with Snap enabled (type of element to snap to: face) so that it sticks to it. Then the animation will be the cylinder increasing its array count and following the curve.

Comment: This was my initial thought,I start doing it and it was like a helling boring work, doing all the head and my second thought was animation nodes, but I couldn't find any reference

Comment: yes a bit boring, but pretty easy to do, but maybe someone will have a better idea  ;)

Comment: Somewhat related .. this [tutorial using Animation Nodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3CwKkiJZN0)

Comment: yessss, just before going for sleep, i think it is a very good start.

Comment: If you succeed in putting some order into that approach, I would love to see your answer to your own question. :)

Comment: You need to clarify **how** should the wire animation look like, it's unclear. How to make the wire is here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94991/trace-visualisation-in-3d-how-to-wrap-curves-onto-a-3d-mesh.

Comment: I don't have much experience with it, myself, but it sounds like you should look into the Build modifier.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial deals with the animation of stuff along curves. Your model might be complicated to set up this up for, though.

[image: Curves animated by Script]

https://medium.com/@behreajj/scripting-curves-in-blender-with-python-c487097efd13

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a sphere.
2. Create couple of curves with depth
3. Use shrinkwrap modifier on each curve. In shrinkwrap modifier turn on "apply on spline" 
   on the top bar.
4. You can animate wires with bevel start/end option in curve panel.