# turning a map into height map

Tags: texturing

How can i change a simple image into height map. I am using crazybump software for making different maps of a picture. But it does not provide the facility to make heigtmap. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you plug image into Height input socket of Bump node in Cycles it will be used as height map (you might want to turn it to greyscale with ColorRamp in between). Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-do-i-make-a-normal-displacement-map-when-all-i-have-is-a-photo

Answer (score 2):

Crazybump doesn't use height map because it is poor. Instead of height map, use normal map - it has much better results on same resolution.

[image]

[image]